# Xcode run to wrong method with same signature

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm encountering some problem with `SVPullToRefresh`.

I'm trying to debug by placing breakpoints in the library. It's strange that no breakpoint is reached after I run.

Then I place breakpoint at my calling as this:

```
[self.tableView addPullToRefreshWithActionHandler:^{ // break point at this line
    [weakSelf needReloadData];
}];
```

Then I run debug `step into`. Wow, what function does it call? It does not call the function in `UIScrollView (SVPullToRefresh)` in `UIScrollView+SVPullToRefresh.m` file.

It call the function in `UIScrollView(Adobe3SVPullToRefresh)` in `UIScrollView+Adobe3SVPullToRefresh.m` line 115. See the image

[image]

What happen with this? Thank you

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: I use SVPullToRefresh https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.